# Named Credential - Status: Unauthorized; Status Code = 401 - Working with Bearer Token but not with Callout

Tags: integration, namedcredentials, datacloud

I have a Legacy Named Credential from UAT that I am porting over to PROD. To test the Named Credential, I am running an Apex Snippet in PROD but I am getting a 401 error. See below:
[image]

However, when I change the Named Cred to a hard-code of the external site (external Data Cloud org) and with a hard-coded Bearer token, **it's working fine**. So at least that means the site is not being blocked:
[image]

Anything else I should check? The Named Cred is authenticated properly. I've tripled check my Auth Provider details, and the Connected App's callback URLs.
[image]

Auth provider:
[image]

Connected App(external Data Cloud Org):
[image]

I feel like I am missing something obvious here but me and my workmates cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. So it was something obvious. During the Authentication on Named Credential, the account that I used to authenticate was the account for my current org. It was supposed to be the account from the EXTERNAL org.